# Python use raw_input with a variable

Tags: python

Is it possible to use raw_input with a variable?

For example.

```
max = 100
value = raw_input('Please enter a value between 10 and' max 'for percentage')
```

Thanks,

Favolas

Comment: This fundamentally has nothing to do with the `raw_input` function and everything to do with getting a variable to appear as part of a string.

Comment: English is not my language so it is difficult to explain me better. You are right Karl.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass anything that evaluates to a string as a parameter:

```
value = raw_input('Please enter a value between 10 and' + str(max) + 'for percentage')
```

use + to concatenate string objects.  You also need to explicitely turn non-strings into string to concatenate them using the str() function.

Answer (score 2):

[Python Language Reference, §5.6.2, "String Formatting Operations"](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Answer (score 1):

i think this might work

```
value = input('Please enter a value between 10 and {} for percentage'.format(max))
```

Answer (score 1):

one more way to do it :)

```
value = raw_input('Please enter a value between 10 and %i for percentage' % (max))
```

Comment: This might be better as a comment on someone else's answer, but if you want to answer the question you could try to let your answer to stand on its own and add examples for the different ways, you also might want to mention Python 3's new [string interpolation features](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)